# R: how is the Pr(>|z|) in the results of glm.fit calculated and why?

Tags: r, linear-model, regression-coefficients, mathematical-statistics

I've been searching but I can't find anywhere an explanation of how the Pr(>|z|) column is calculated in the results of R's glm.fit function.
I would really appreciate:
a) an explanation so I can calculate that column myself
b) an explanation of why it's calculated in that way
c) a link to somewhere where I can read the theory behind it so I can conceptually understand its meaning
Thanks very much in advance!

Following Tim's comment: what type of Wald test? With what hypotheses? And what does Pr(>|z|) even mean? Assuming Pr() means probability and |z| means absolute value, why is there nothing to the left of the > sign?

As far as I can see, none of these things are documented, let alone explained. Could an expert please shed some light on my questions?
Thank you very very much.

I have to keep editing this question in response to comments because apparently I don't have enough reputation to write comments :(

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that $\Pr(>|z|)$ has no sense. It should be $\Pr(|X|>|z|)$ where $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $z$ is observed z value.

The calculation of it should be:

$$\Pr(|X|>|z|)=\Phi(-|z|) + 1 - \Phi(|z|) = 2\Phi(-|z|)$$ where $\Phi$ is CDF of standard normal distribution.